# Cannot install packages (trying to resolve: could not find pkg cfg file provided by X)

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-kinetic, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am runnig ROS kinetic on an Uuntu 16.04 and I downloaded a repository from  github and pasted it into the src directory of my catkin_ws, but whenever I run "catkin_make" I always get this error:

```
-- Could not find the required component 'controller_manager'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "controller_manager" with any of the following names:

    controller_managerConfig.cmake
    controller_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "controller_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "controller_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "controller_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I tried downloading the controller_manager package by downloading ros_control with the following command from ros.org:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control ros-kinetic-ros-controllers
```

However, when I try this command, I'm getting these errors:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-hardware-interface amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-132757-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-controller-interface amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-133652-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-realtime-tools amd64 1.11.1-0xenial-20190320-130942-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-171041-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-ackermann-steering-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-175427-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-combined-robot-hw amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-133622-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-controller-manager-msgs amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20180824-100448-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-controller-manager amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-134400-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-controller-manager-tests amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-153143-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:10 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-combined-robot-hw-tests amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-154237-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:11 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-control-toolbox amd64 1.17.0-0xenial-20190320-143943-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:12 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-forward-command-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-140150-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:13 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-effort-controllers amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-144804-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:14 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-force-torque-sensor-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-134405-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:15 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-gripper-action-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-153653-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:16 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-imu-sensor-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-142735-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:17 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-joint-limits-interface amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-141139-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:18 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-142742-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:19 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-153657-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:20 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-position-controllers amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-140709-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-transmission-interface amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-133548-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:22 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-ros-control amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-171054-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:23 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-135555-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:24 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-velocity-controllers amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-144818-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err:25 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-ros-controllers amd64 0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-180510-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-hardware-interface/ros-kinetic-hardware-interface_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-132757-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-controller-interface/ros-kinetic-controller-interface_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-133652-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-realtime-tools/ros-kinetic-realtime-tools_1.11.1-0xenial-20190320-130942-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller/ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-171041-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-ackermann-steering-controller/ros-kinetic-ackermann-steering-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-175427-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-combined-robot-hw/ros-kinetic-combined-robot-hw_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-133622-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-controller-manager-msgs/ros-kinetic-controller-manager-msgs_0.13.3-0xenial-20180824-100448-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-controller-manager/ros-kinetic-controller-manager_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-134400-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-controller-manager-tests/ros-kinetic-controller-manager-tests_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-153143-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-combined-robot-hw-tests/ros-kinetic-combined-robot-hw-tests_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-154237-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-control-toolbox/ros-kinetic-control-toolbox_1.17.0-0xenial-20190320-143943-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-forward-command-controller/ros-kinetic-forward-command-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-140150-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-effort-controllers/ros-kinetic-effort-controllers_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-144804-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-kinetic-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-134405-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-gripper-action-controller/ros-kinetic-gripper-action-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-153653-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-imu-sensor-controller/ros-kinetic-imu-sensor-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-142735-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-joint-limits-interface/ros-kinetic-joint-limits-interface_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-141139-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller/ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-142742-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller/ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-153657-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-position-controllers/ros-kinetic-position-controllers_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-140709-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-transmission-interface/ros-kinetic-transmission-interface_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-133548-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-ros-control/ros-kinetic-ros-control_0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-171054-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller/ros-kinetic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-135555-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-velocity-controllers/ros-kinetic-velocity-controllers_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-144818-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-ros-controllers/ros-kinetic-ros-controllers_0.13.5-0xenial-20190320-180510-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325728/cannot-install-packages-(trying-to-resolve:-could-not-find-pkg-cfg-file-provided-by-x)/) by [Gi99](https://answers.ros.org/users/41689/gi99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-06-13**:
Have you tried doing what it says and running `apt-get update`?
Have you [updated your keys for the package repositories?](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-gpg-keys-deployed-for-packages-ros-org/9454)

**Comment by [tomsepe](https://answers.ros.org/users/39314/tomsepe/) on 2019-06-16**:
I'm having a similar issue anbd --fix missing doens't work either

**Comment by [tomsepe](https://answers.ros.org/users/39314/tomsepe/) on 2019-06-16**:
I get this:

Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Fetched 230 kB in 1s (203 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Geoff hints at, this is most likely caused by the key switch.

Refer to #q325039.

> I downloaded a repository from github and pasted it into the src directory of my catkin_ws, but whenever I run "catkin_make" I always get this error:

Please note that just cloning a single repository into your workspace will not work in most cases. You'll have to make sure to have installed all required dependencies.

See the answer to #q252478 for an example workflow.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gi99](https://answers.ros.org/users/41689/gi99/) on 2019-06-17**:
I tried what @Geoff said and it worked! I updated my keys and used `sudo apt-get update`.
The problem with  #q252478 workflow is that I am following a script and when I use git clone (...) it asks for an username and a password that I don't have. But if I had the password and username, I think it would've worked.
Thanks a lot!